# Program jumping to a function that wasn't called

Tags: python-2.7, function, pygame, boolean

I'm working on a game. Now, in my game when i get to a specific place (a function) called "room01" though I haven't further instructed it where/how to proceed onwards, it jumps back to a place in kitchen function. Why is this happening?

I'm new and i couldn't figure out how i could demonstrate my problem otherwise. Here is my complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

def entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked):
    if already_there_ent == False:
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")
        print "You are standing at the entrance hall of an apartment.The door you came through won't open.\
        \nTo your immediate right is the kitchen(0),\
        \nTo your left ahead is the main Lounge(1),\
        \nStraight ahead is Room 1's door(2).\
        \nFind you're way out!"
        choice01 = raw_input("Where do you go? > ")

        if choice01 == "right" or choice01 == "kitchen" or choice01 == "0" or choice01 == "go right" or choice01 == "go to kitchen":
            kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        elif choice01 == "left" or choice01 == "main lounge" or choice01 == "1" or choice01 == "go left" or choice01 == "go to main lounge":
            main_lounge(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        elif choice01 == "room" or choice01 == "straight" or choice01 == "2" or choice01 == "go straight" or choice01 == "go to room":
            room01(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        else:
            print "Not a valid option."
            raw_input("> ")
            already_there_ent = True
            entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)


    elif already_there_ent == True:
        choice01 = raw_input("Where do you go? > ")

        if choice01 == "right" or choice01 == "kitchen" or choice01 == "0" or choice01 == "go right" or choice01 == "go to kitchen":
            kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        elif choice01 == "left" or choice01 == "main lounge" or choice01 == "1" or choice01 == "go left" or choice01 == "go to main lounge":
            main_Lounge(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        elif choice01 == "room" or choice01 == "straight" or choice01 == "2" or choice01 == "go straight" or choice01 == "go to room":
            room01(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        else:
            print "Not a valid option."
            raw_input(">")
            already_there_ent = True
            entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)


def kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked):
    alias = {
    '0': '0',
    'first cupboard': '0',
    'check first cupboard': '0',
    'open first cupboard': '0',
    '1': '1',
    'second cupboard': '1',
    'check second cupboard': '1',
    'open second cupboard': '1',
    '2': '2',
    'third cupboard': '2',
    'check third cupboard': '2',
    'open third cupboard': '2',
    '3': '3',
    'read letter': '3',
    'check letter': '3',
    }

    dic = {
    "0":"You see a dusty empty bottles of milks, with spiderwebs at the corners of the cupboard. Nothing of Interest here.",  \
    "1":"You see some packs of likely expired cereal and a key(0).",  \
    "2":"You see an empty or dusty cupboard. Nothing of interest here.", \
    "3":"Dear Shawn..... nothing of interest",
    }


    if already_there_kit == False:
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")
        print "There are 3 different cupboards(0, 1, 2) or a letter(3) placed on the counter."
        choice02 = raw_input("What do you do? > ")

        if choice02 == "leave kitchen" or choice02 == "entrance hall" or choice02 == "back" or choice02 == "go to entrance hall":
            already_there_ent = False
            already_there_kit = False
            entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        elif choice02 in alias:
            print dic[alias[choice02]]
            if choice02 == "1":
                print "..."
                choice02_key = raw_input("What do you do? >")
                if choice02_key == "pick key" or choice02_key == "0" or choice02_key == "key":
                    print("---------------------------------------------------------")
                    print "You picked the key. It probably unlocks some door."
                    key_picked = True
                    already_there_kit = True
                    kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
                elif choice02 == "leave kitchen" or choice02 == "entrance hall" or choice02 == "back" or choice02 == "go to entrance hall":
                    already_there_ent = False
                    already_there_kit = False
                    entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
            already_there_kit = True
            kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        else:
            print "Not a valid Option."
            already_there_kit = True
            kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)



    elif already_there_kit == True:
        print "..."
        choice02 = raw_input("What do you do? >")

        if choice02 == "leave kitchen" or choice02 == "entrance hall" or choice02 == "back" or choice02 == "go to entrance hall":
            already_there_ent = False
            already_there_kit = False
            entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        elif choice02 in alias:
            print dic[alias[choice02]]
            if choice02 == "1":
                print "..."
                choice02_key = raw_input("What do you do? >")
                if choice02_key == "pick key" or choice02_key == "0" or choice02_key == "key":
                    print("---------------------------------------------------------")
                    print "You picked the key. It probably unlocks some door."
                    key_picked = True
                    already_there_kit = True
                    kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
                elif choice02 == "leave kitchen" or choice02 == "entrance hall" or choice02 == "back" or choice02 == "go to entrance hall":
                    already_there_ent = False
                    already_there_kit = False
                    entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
            already_there_kit = True
            kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
        else:
            print "Not a valid Option."
            already_there_kit = True
            kitchen(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)





def room01(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked):
    if key_picked == True:
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")
        print "You unlocked the room using the key."
        raw_input("> ")
        print "You are now inside the room!. There is a bed, 2 drawers on its sides.\
        \n The only window the room has is barricaded with iron grills.\
        \n Apart, from that there is a fine painting of an old man on the western side wall."
        choice02 = raw_input("What do you do? ")


    elif key_picked == False:
        print "This room is locked."
        already_there_ent = True
        entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)


def main_lounge(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked):
    print "Hmm.. How do i make this game interesting?"
    entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)




#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

print "Welcome to the game"
raw_input("Press RETURN to start the hunt or CTRL + C to quit anytime.")
print "Hint: Make use the keys to easily navigate through i.e. xyz(1) or do not use CAPS in your input."
raw_input("> ")

already_there_ent = False
already_there_kit = False
already_there_room = False
already_there_lounge = False
key_picked = False
entrance_hall(already_there_ent, already_there_kit, already_there_room, already_there_lounge, key_picked)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your function ends it returns back to where it was called and then the program continue to the next line after the function call.
It is just how functions work

Comment: Yes, but it was called from entrance_hall function, not the kitchen function. Then why is it returning to the kitchen?

Comment: `kitchen()` calls `entrance_hall()` and `entrance_hall()` calls `room01()`. If `room01()` exits and `entrance_hall()` also exits, you end up back in `kitchen()`.

Comment: Okay. That sounds reasonable, but how do i stop it from returning?

Comment: You can stop the program using raise SystemExit(0)